# Reading schema multiple parquet files from Azure blob

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I want to read multiple parquet files from Azure blob storage through databricks but problem will be the schema. If I use inferSchema as True then it will take out schema from first file it will read. Is there any way to infer schema after reading a number of files or after reading a definite volume of data.
We don't want to use mergeSchema as True.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you want to achieve like sample schema? And are you trying to read these files into a single dataframe?

Comment: Yes I want to read those files in a single dataframe. And I want to omit the possibility of leaving any extra columns in any of the parquet files. So suppose if any data file contain any extra column I want to consider that in my data.

Comment: Is there any key column common for all those files?

Comment: All the columns are same but I am looking for the solution of the scenario "if an extra non-ket column got added then what to do"

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to infer schema after reading a number of files or after reading a definite volume of data.

**AFAIK**, There might not be any such methods.

You can try the below approach by which I am able to get the desired result.

First get the parquet file path which has a greater number of columns from the files list. Now, get the schema of that particular file and enforce this schema to all files.

Please go through a sample demonstration below:

These are my parquet files in the Blob storage in which the **`xyz.parquet`** has one extra column than others.

[image]

After Mounting, Get the list of file paths and find the parquet which has a greater number of columns.

[image]

Now, get the schema of this parquet file

[image]

Enforce this custom schema to multiple parquet files, so that we can get the dataframe with desired schema.

[image]

You can see that we got the extra column and for the files which does not have that columns the value will be null.

**My Source Code:**

```
#File paths list
fileinfo=dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/mnt/blob1/myfiles/")
paths=[i[0] for i in fileinfo]
print(paths)

#Finding the required file path
col_num=[]
for file_path in paths:
    df=spark.read.parquet(file_path)
    col_num.append(len(df.columns))
i=col_num.index(max(col_num))
our_path=paths[i]
print(our_path)

#Schema
myschema=spark.read.parquet(our_path).schema
print(myschema)

#Enforcing the schema to all files
result_df = spark.read.format("parquet").schema(myschema).load("dbfs:/mnt/blob1/myfiles/")
display(result_df)
```

Comment: One problem is I won't know which file has greatest number of columns. It should be handled dynamically.

Comment: Yeah, the code I have given will find the path of the that file for you.

Comment: There are a large number of files at that location. After getting a file with maximum column then how to exclude it from reading again. I need to insert those files in one go and after reading files will not move to another folder.

Comment: After getting the file with maximum number of columns, I am getting the schema of it and enforcing the same schema to all files while reading. If look at my code first I am reading all files as dataframe to get the file path of the file which has max number of columns. Then using the schema of it.

Comment: #Enforcing the schema to all files
result_df = spark.read.format("parquet").schema(myschema).load("dbfs:/mnt/blob1/myfiles/")
display(result_df)   This code will read all files at one go with the schema of max number of columns file.